# Significance scores in numeric instead of stars

Tags: ggpairs

In `GGally::ggpairs` correlation values are shown with *'s as seen in the figure below. I'd like to change the *s to show the numerical significance values.

```
GGally::ggpairs(data = iris[, 1:4],
upper=list(continuous=wrap(ggally_cor,displayGrid=FALSE, stars=TRUE)))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAIHW.png)

I tried to extract the significance values in a function before the graph, but I can't integrate them to ggpairs afterward.